# South Australian provisional driving licence to a US licence

Tags: australia, driving-license

I have held my P1 (Provisional) Licence here in South Australia for 8 months now. I would like to visit the States and get a full licence there (Overseas Driving Permit is not an option for me) and then come back to Australia to transfer my American Licence to get my Full Open licence here.

I do not plan to actually drive in the States, just hold a licence.

I heard this was possible from a friend who works in the Department of Motor vehicle service office, and wanted to confirm before I plan a holiday overseas.

Is the process difficult to transfer my licence?
Do I need to do testing?
What paperwork is required?
I do not care what state I have to go to, just whatever is easiest...

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to circumvent the law?

Comment: I just don't want to be on my Provisional licence for 3 years (2.5years to go) It has been done before as my friend issues licences here in Australia but he cant remember what countries can do straight transfers.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, licenses are issued by the individual states. Tourists can typically drive for a limited time using their non-US licenses. However, I'm a retired attorney and I've never heard of any state accepting a non-US license as a method to bypass any part of the state licensing procedure.

Each state's Department of Motor Vehicles maintain on-line web pages where you can research state requirements for licensure. I just checked California and Nevada, which behave in the manner I describe above — that is, no credit is given for non-US licenses.

IOW, having a non-US license is irrelevant, and an adult applicant for a US state drivers license must begin the state's application process from the beginning. *(See 8-10-18 edit below about license reciprocity between France and the US states of Texas, Oklahoma, and Arkansas.)*

In the US, applicants must pass both theory testing and on-the-road driving testing, and must provide a licensed and insured vehicle in which to be tested. For those over 18, there is usually no minimum time period in a restricted license class, one may submit to testing right away. Remember too that states issue licenses to their residents, and you'd have to demonstrate that you are a resident.

All in all, then, your plan of using your current Australian limited license is not going to confer any advantage on you in applying for a US license.

If you did obtain a US license, I have no idea if holding a US license might allow you to directly obtain a Full Open license in Australia. That's a question for someone familiar with Australian law.

———————————————-

Edited 8-10-18:

Thanks to @MJeffryes, who has commented below that France has reciprocal license-exchange agreements with the US states of Texas, Oklahoma, and Arkansas. Exchange is possible there bi-directionally upon proof of residence.

Edited 9-4-18:

This [SE.StackExchange item](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9142/not-having-to-surrender-a-german-drivers-license-when-getting-a-us-license) says that the state of Pennsylvania has similar reciprocity.

I'm not aware of any other country/US state combinations that allow exchange.

Comment: *IOW, having a non-US license is irrelevant, and an adult applicant for a US state drivers license must begin the state's application process from the beginning.* This is absolutely not true. As you say, driver licensing is a matter for states. As such, some states have made reciprocal agreements with foreign governments to allow driving license exchange. For example, [France has agreements with Texas, Oklahoma, and Arkansas](https://houston.consulfrance.org/spip.php?article1586) (link in French). I don't know whether this applies to Australian licenses, but in principle, it could do.

Comment: Thanks, @MJeffryes. I wasn't aware of those reciprocities. I have amended my answer to include them.